# finding volume bound by cylinder, cone, and xy plane

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate the volume of a solid enclosed by the cone $z= \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$, the cylinder $(x+3/2)^2 + y^2 = 9/4$, and the plane $z=0$.

When I converted to cylindrical formulas I got
$z=0
,z=p
,p=-3\cos(\theta)$
but I am having troubles on the limits.

Answer (score 1):

For a correct set up of the integral we need to make a sketch similar to this one here attached for $z-x/y$ and $x-y$ planes.

[image]

In cylindrical coordinates the region is determined by

- $0\le z \le \frac32$
- $\theta_{1}(z)\le \theta \le \theta_{2}(z)$
- $z\le r \le -\frac32 \cos \theta$

and for symmetry we can also consider twice the integral over the region

- $0\le z \le \frac32$
- $\theta_{1}(z)\le \theta \le \pi$
- $z\le r \le -\frac32 \cos \theta$

thus we only need to find $\theta_1(z)$ to obtain the correct set up.

Comment: I want to ask one thing , you'll  find it funny . How to draw this kind of graphs , I mean is there any software or app???

Comment: @PrithiviRaj Those are made by hand with windows journal